# How to open a existing controller in Alloy framework Titanium SDK (Appcelerator)

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

i am not been able to open a existing Alloy controller within another controller .js file.

i have tried opening the controller using require method but returned exceptions.

// On click Function Index.js

```
function Done(e) {
   if(($.user.value=="admin") && ($.pass.value=="123"))
   {
       alert($.user.value);
       var ne = require('home');
       ne.open();                
       $.index.close(); 
   }
}

$.index.open();
```

Where Home is a Alloy Controller.

Exception Caught are :-

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to instantiate the 'home' controller and open its window.

```
var ne = Alloy.createController('home').getView();
ne.open();
```